# Java Type Cast, Object Type and overloading Issue

Tags: java, casting, overloading

Please have a look on following Class, I need to check if there is valid value in the variable. All works fine if there is a proper value in variable instead of `null`, When it comes null the behaviour is not what I expect (Although it might make sense if `Integer a = null;` when checked as `a instanceof Integer`,

Can some one guide me how to achieve correct result from following class?

```
package com.mazhar.hassan;

public class ValueChecker {
    public static boolean empty(Integer value) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
        return (value != null && value.intValue() > 0);
    }
    public static boolean empty(Long value) {
        System.out.println("Long");
        return (value != null && value.longValue() > 0);
    }
    public static boolean empty(String value) {
        System.out.println("String");
        return (value != null && value.length() > 0);
    }
    public static boolean empty(Object value) {
        System.out.println("Object");
        return (value != null);
    }
    public static void checkAll(Object... args) {
        for(Object o: args) {
            if (o instanceof Integer) {
                empty((Integer)o);
            }
            else if (o instanceof Long) {
                empty((Long)o);
            }
            else if (o instanceof String) {
                empty((String)o);
            }
            else {
                empty(o);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Integer a = null;
        Long b =  null;
        String x = null;
        Object y = null;

        if (a instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("a is Integer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("a is not Integer");
        }

        System.out.println("/---------------------------------------------------/");
        checkAll(a,b,x,y);
        System.out.println("/---------------------------------------------------/");
        empty(a);
        empty(b);
        empty(x);
        empty(y);
    }
}
```

Why I need exact type checking is, I thave to throw erros like "Not valid Integer", "No valid Long" etc.

The output of above class is as follows.

```
/-----------------------(Output 1)----------------------------/
a is not Integer
/-----------------------(Output 2)----------------------------/
Object
Object
Object
Object
/------------------------(Output 3)---------------------------/
Integer
Long
String
Object
```

Output 1: a is not integer (checked by instanceof) can not recognize it but when passed to a overloaded function goes to the right function (Output 3)

Output 2: How to achieve `checkAll` with multiple/dynamic param checkAll(varInt, varLong, varString, varObject)

Comment: I think you should raise a generic null pointer error, something like "the field can't be null", and if there is any data then validate the concrete format (in that case you don't even need the instance of). This will also avoid glue code (copy and paste if xxx!=null). Let me know if this fits your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour for Output 1 is caused by the fact that method overloads are bound at ***compile* time.** So the specific overload to pick is bound before the program even runs. `instanceof`, on the other hand, is a runtime check.

Thus, at runtime `a instanceof Integer` is effectively `null instanceof Integer`, which is obviously `false`.

But for each of those individual method calls, the proper method is called because the compiler bound the specific overload of the method at compile time, based on the reference type of the variable. Thus:

```
empty(a); // Compiled to a call to empty(Integer value)
empty(b); // Compiled to a call to empty(Long value)
empty(x); // Compiled to a call to empty(String value)
empty(y); // Compiled to a call to empty(Object value)
```

So regardless of the actual object that `a`, `b`, `x`, and `y` reference, you'll always get the right output on your console for the respective object.

---

> Output 2: How to achieve checkAll with multiple/dynamic param checkAll(varInt, varLong, varString, varObject)

Well, if you're going to pass `null`, you can't really. `null` is `null` at runtime, and doesn't have any type information associated with it. The JVM can't tell that one null is a "`String null`" or an "`Object null`". It's just `null`. So you can't really implement the multiple check you want to for `null` inputs -- `null instanceof ______` will always return `false`, so you'll always end up with your default case.

If you pass actual objects, though, that method *should* work properly.

Comment: @NetSurgeon Thanks! Fun fact: If you replace any of the `empty(_)` with `empty(null)`, you'll get a compiler error because the compiler can't figure out what method to bind. Can't imagine that being too helpful, though.

Comment: Oh yes if null is directly passed its a compiler error. nice thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**problem:**

```
    Integer a = null;
    Long b =  null;
    String x = null;
    Object y = null;
```

You cant use `instanceof` on null values, it expect the objects to be instantiated thus giving you wrong result.

**solution:**

instantaite the object first before you check for instance.

Comment: Correct, that's what I have understood from above experience. but If you see the 3rd output, The overloaded functions are recognizing the type of these null variables. I need to know how they are doing that?

Comment: That was not me(the -ve)

Comment: @NetSurgeon umm because you print it before you check.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you check instanceof in your loop, you are checking `null`.   `null` is not an instance of anything, it is the absence of an instance.

If you want to achieve something like this, you're going to have to change your API for `checkAll(Object ...)` to something that tells the function what types to expect:

```
public class ValueChecker {
    public static boolean checkAll(Object[] args, Class<?>[] types) {
        if (args == null || types == null || args.length != types.length)
            throw new RuntimeException("programming error");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (types[i] == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("programming error");
            if (args[i] == null || !types[i].isAssignableFrom(args[i].getClass())) {
                System.out.println("arg " + (i +1) + " is not " + types[i].getSimpleName());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer a = null;
        Long b =  null;
        String x = null;
        Object y = null;

        checkAll(
                new Object[] {a, b, x, y},
                new Class<?>[] {Integer.class, Long.class, String.class, Object.class}
        );
    }
}
```